# Should I make separate ERC20 wallets for each token?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, wallets, ledger-nano-s, altcoin

When I create an Ethereum wallet on my hardware wallet (Ledger Nano), or a web wallet (Metamask), is it possible to mix UNI token and ETH together in that same single wallet address? Or must a separate ERC20 wallet be made for the UNI token? In other words, can Ethereum addresses contain a diverse collection of tokens, or is it only one token per wallet?

If so, what if I send a token like UNI to an ERC20 address that is filled with Ether? Is there an error or loss ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single Ethereum address can manage both ethers and tokens, providing the wallet supports the token standard.

Ledger and Metamask support ERC20 :

- To manage ERC20 with ledger see this : https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005197845-Manage-ERC20-tokens.
- To add UNI to Metamask you just need the contract [address](https://etherscan.io/address/0x1f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984), more info here : https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015489031-How-to-View-Your-Tokens.

> What if I send a token like UNI to an ERC20 address that is filled with Ether? Is there an error or loss ?

There is no such a concept of "ERC20 address". You just have Ethereum addresses which manage ethers and interact with smart contracts. A wallet can manage tokens such as ERC20,ERC721 by supporting their standard interface. If the wallet does not support a specific token, one could write a script to directly interact with the token contract.

Comment: so one ethereum address alone can contain 20 ETH, 200 UNI, 50 Chainlink, 30 MAKR, 40 AAVE?

Comment: and about the sending a token to an ethereum wallet that has only been initiated for Ether, and *not yet set up to manage any other token*, does the transaction fail since it doesn't know how to interact with that token?

Comment: `so one ethereum address alone can contain 20 ETH, 200 UNI, 50 Chainlink, 30 MAKR, 40 AAVE?`. Yes, that's it.

Comment: For your second question the answer is no.

Comment: if no, then what does the transaction do? it automatically carves out a new partition of the  ethereum wallet for the new token just received? For example, if my purely ETH wallet receives an unsolicited donation of 10 UNI tokens with no preparation whatsoever, I will suddenly see this balance of UNI appear in the wallet without error?

Comment: If it's a ERC20 you will see it with Etherscan (https://etherscan.io/) by entering your address in the search bar. For exemple see the UNI contract here : https://etherscan.io/address/0x1f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984. You can see, in the token section, all the tokens detained by the address. With Metamask you sometimes need to manually add the token (see the link in my answer) to display it.

Comment: Note that all the major wallets support ERC20 so you should be fine with this standard.

Comment: ok so in the metamask case, the transaction will go through unimpeded, but I wouldn't see it until I manually add/link the token to that ethereum address. until I do, the tokens would be there, but hidden?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: so effectively transacting with an ethereum address bonds all transactions, regardless of denomination, to that address as well as omnipotently to the private keys (phrase) tied to that address. Restoring that Metamask wallet with the key phrases on 5 different systems in the same day will always each recover all balances for any tokens that have interacted with that address?

Comment: Yes but I think you will need to "re-add" the different tokens for each wallet of each system.